# How to define Active Directory Domain Service's network interface?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I bind AD DS to a specific NIC? I have two NICs in a VM running Windows Server 2008 R2. One to connect to the physical network and one to connect to a few Windows 7 clients on a separate subnet. The multi-homed Server 2008 R2 guest runs AD DS, and I only want it to be bound to the interface which is connected to the other virtual machines. I couldn't figure out from the wizard, which interface will be used.

Comment: It's not best practice to multi-home a DC. So it may he a trick question. In a real production environment you wouldn't do this at all.

Comment: I don't want to multi-home it, I want it bound to one interface only. How to do this? Wasn't revealed by the "setup wizard".

Comment: You *are* multi homing it. You have two NICs on two different networks. That's multi homing.

Comment: Also, homework questions are off-topic per [about] and the [help]. I've edited those portions of your question out so that it doesn't get closed, as it can still be relevant without those tidbits of information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you should not be multi-homing a domain controller.

You cannot tell AD DS to bind to a specific network adapter. What you do in this instance is prevent one of the network adapters from automatically registering DNS records. This will prevent anything from trying to authenticate to that interface, as clients will not be able to locate it.

Comment: Putting two NICs  in the server *is* multihoming it. Period.

Comment: Aw, shucks. Now I feel bad about my dozens of production DCs with two NICs in them... granted, the other NIC has no DNS server IPs configured and no default gateway, and is only used to run backups on a separate LAN, but still.  ;)

Comment: @RyanRies - OK, but you know what you're doing.

Comment: And why would you need to be backing up dozens of DCs? (Assuming they're all in the same domain of course.) You can just do a few of them. Waste of tape space :-)